# Rename characters as condition of another column, R

Tags: r

I want to replace some labels in a column based on the data in the next column.  I found a couple ways to do this on SO, but they are not working.

Basically if the "plot" is 11, I want the "trt" column to read "SC" (right now it reads S2 or C2).

I've tried

```
cn[cn$plot == 11, "trt"]="SC"
cn$trt[cn$plot == "11"]<-"SC"
```

But I get

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, cn$plot == 11, value = c(NA, NA, NA, NA,  :
invalid factor level, NA generated
```

for the first and

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = c("SC", "SC", "SC", "SC",  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

for the second.

I've tried 11 both `as.factor` and `as.numeric`.

Comment: Try `as.character` next :-)

Comment: (That is, convert "trt" to a column of "character" values--right now, it is a column of factors, and none of the levels include "SC". Alternatively, add the level "SC" to the "trt" column and try again.)

Comment: Yes!  'df$trt<-as.character(df.trt)` was all I needed.

Comment: Alternatively, you presumably read in the data with the default `stringsAsFactors=TRUE` argument in, e.g., `read.csv`. Set that to `FALSE` initially and you can avoid these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This basically means that you're trying to assign a `level` in a `factor` variable (a column in your `data.frame` in this case) when that `level` doesn't exist.

The easiest solution is to use `as.character` on your `factor` vector.

Here's a simple example:

```
A <- factor(c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
B <- as.character(A)

A
# [1] A B C D
# Levels: A B C D
B
# [1] "A" "B" "C" "D"

A[A == "C"] <- "E"
# Warning message:
# In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, A == "C", value = "E") :
#   invalid factor level, NA generated

A <- factor(c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
levels(A)[which(levels(A) == "C")] <- "E"
A
# [1] A B E D
# Levels: A B E D


B[B == "C"] <- "E"
B
# [1] "A" "B" "E" "D"
```